# How can I edit the CSS of the WPBakery pageable container on my Wordpress page?

Tags: css, wordpress, element, wpbakery

I'm using WPBakery on this [wordpress site](https://www.wavesvienna.com). I'm using an element called pageable content container as you can see on the front page. It has several slides which are changing every few seconds.

My problem is that every time the slide changes the container changes its size and gets smaller until the animation is finished. The whole bottom of the site moves. There are options to turn of or change the animations but it doesn't seem to do the trick. It just looks ugly.

My guess is that I have to give the container a fixed size via CSS? Or is there any other way? Appreciate your help.

I already tried everything whithin the WPbakery user interface. I can't turn of the basic animation which comes from bottom to top.

I also tried giving it an extra css class name and editing the custom css with height. But it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a minimum height for `.vc_tta-panels`. I tried this and it seems to have fixed it. However, the height of each slide will change depending on the amount of content you have in it...

```
.vc_tta-panels {
    min-height: 200px;
}
```